# Compiling simple parallel function gives inconsistent results and errors

Tags: warning-messages, parallelization, compile

Im trying to compile the following function:

```
n := 5

fc = Compile[{{l,_Integer,1}},
    a=1;b=1;
    Do[
        If[l[[i]]==1,
            a=a+2b; b=b+i,
            b=a+b;  a=a+i],
        {i,n}];
    b,
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True]

fc[Tuples[{0,1},n]]
```

However this gives the following errors:

> CompiledFunction::pext: Instruction 1 in CompiledFunction[{10,11.2,5852},{{_Integer,1}},{{2,1,0},{2,0,1}},{{0,{2,0,2}},<<1>>,{1,{<<1>>}}},<<1>>,{{46,Function[{l},a=1],2,1,0,6,0,17},{46,Function[{l},b=1],2,1,0,6,0,17},{46,Function[{l},n],2,1,0,3,0,2},{40,50,3,0,2,2,0,1},<<10>>,{4,3,1,-8},{46,Function[{l},b],2,1,0,2,0,1},{1}},Function[{l},a=1;b=1;Do[If[l[[i]]==1,a=Plus[<<2>>];b=Plus[<<2>>],b=Plus[<<2>>];a=Plus[<<2>>]],{i,n}];b,Listable],Evaluate] calls ordinary code that can be evaluated on only one thread at a time.

and

> CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

Additionally, the result is often wrong and inconsistent. It works correctly when `Parallelization` is turned off. Am I doing something wrong here or is there just something wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `CompilePrint` your compiled function, you'll see lots of calls to `MainEvaluate`:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[fc]
```

> ```
>     1 argument
>     1 Boolean register
>     11 Integer registers
>     1 Tensor register
>     Underflow checking off
>     Overflow checking off
>     Integer overflow checking on
>     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
>
>     T(I1)0 = A1
>     I5 = 0
>     I1 = 5
>     I8 = 2
>     I0 = 1
>     Result = I2
>
>  1    V17 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{l}, a = 1][ T(I1)0]]
>  2    V17 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{l}, b = 1][ T(I1)0]]
>  3    I4 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{l}, n][ T(I1)0]]
>  4    I6 = I5
>  5    goto 14
>  6    I7 = Part[ T(I1)0, I6]
>  7    B0 = I7 == I0
>  8    if[ !B0] goto 12
>  9    V17I6 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{l, iCompile$9}, Block[{i = iCompile$9}, {a = a + 2 b, i}]][ T(I1)0, I6]]
>  10   V17I6 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{l, iCompile$10}, Block[{i = iCompile$10}, {b = b + i, i}]][ T(I1)0, I6]]
>  11   goto 14
>  12   V17I6 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{l, iCompile$11}, Block[{i = iCompile$11}, {b = a + b, i}]][ T(I1)0, I6]]
>  13   V17I6 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{l, iCompile$12}, Block[{i = iCompile$12}, {a = a + i, i}]][ T(I1)0, I6]]
>  14   if[ ++ I6 <= I4] goto 6
>  15   I2 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{l}, b][ T(I1)0]]
>  16   Return
> ```

To avoid these calls to `MainEvaluate`, you should modularize the variables `a` and `b`. Also, the global variable `n` needs to have a value. So:

```
Clear[fc]
fc[n_] := Compile[{{l,_Integer,1}},
    Module[{a=1, b=1},
        Do[
            If[l[[i]]==1,
                a = a + 2b; b = b + i,
                b = a + b; a = a + i
            ],
            {i,n}
        ];
        b
    ],
    RuntimeAttributes->{Listable},
    Parallelization->True
];
```

Now, `fc[n]` has no calls to `MainEvaluate`:

```
n := 5;
CompilePrint[fc[n]]
```

> ```
>     1 argument
>     1 Boolean register
>     10 Integer registers
>     1 Tensor register
>     Underflow checking off
>     Overflow checking off
>     Integer overflow checking on
>     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
>
>     T(I1)0 = A1
>     I3 = 0
>     I1 = 5
>     I6 = 2
>     I0 = 1
>     Result = I4
>
> 1   I2 = I0
> 2   I4 = I0
> 3   I7 = I1
> 4   I5 = I3
> 5   goto 19
> 6   I8 = Part[ T(I1)0, I5]
> 7   B0 = I8 == I0
> 8   if[ !B0] goto 15
> 9   I8 = I6 * I4
> 10  I9 = I2 + I8
> 11  I2 = I9
> 12  I9 = I4 + I5
> 13  I4 = I9
> 14  goto 19
> 15  I9 = I2 + I4
> 16  I4 = I9
> 17  I9 = I2 + I5
> 18  I2 = I9
> 19  if[ ++ I5 <= I7] goto 6
> 20  Return
> ```

Check:

```
fc[n][Tuples[{0,1},n]]
```

> {26, 20, 35, 17, 35, 24, 37, 16, 32, 24, 43, 19, 39, 26, 39, 16, 30, 23, 42, 19, 42, 28, 43, 17, 35, 26, 47, 20, 41, 27, 40, 16}

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `CompilePrint`, that's very useful.

Comment: I have a question related to this: what if I want to use custom compiled functions inside fc? I have the same error message which is apparently related to the calls to MainEvaluate when I call the custom functions.